# Need help fixing VScode C++ formatting error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work with C++ and VS code. I want to use VS Code because I already use it for web dev + plan to work with particle.io whose workbench runs on VS code.

I'm having a problem with auto formatting. When I try I get an error that says "Extension 'Emmet' cannot format [the path to my file]". I actually had the same problem when I set up flutter / dart as well. Now I have this line in my settings.json.

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.emmet",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    },
```

Do I need a C++ equivalent as I have for dart there?

Anyone is greatly appreciated!

Thanks